# invalid xml request for calculator service

Tags: axis2c

I'm completely new to axis2c and I've just downloaded and unpacked
 axis2c 1.6 for Windows (binary release).
I've followed the installation instructions and have successfully
started axis2_http_server.
 Trying to access the Calculator service's WSDL works fine  but any call to
 the service's add method returns "invalid XML in request" as well as the
 same text is shown in the console window where axis2_http_server is
 running.
I've also tried soapUI. The request shown is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope

 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

  xmlns:typ="http://ws.apache.org/axis2/services/Calculator/types">

<soapenv:Header/>

<soapenv:Body>

  <typ:add>

     <param_1>1.0</param_1>

     <param_2>1.0</param_2>

  </typ:add>
```

The response is

```
  <soapenv:Fault>

     <faultcode>soapenv:Sender</faultcode>

     <faultstring>Invalid XML format in request</faultstring>

  </soapenv:Fault>
```

The problem is issued in in `calc.c (function axis2_calc_add())`, where
`seq_node = axiom_node_get_first_child(complex_node, env);`
returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Calculator service example has multiple issues that prevents it to work.

Firstly, implementation of `add` operation is invalid, it expects request like that (here is only contents of soap body):

```
<typ:add>
    <complex_node>
        <seq_node>
            <param_1>1</param_1>
            <param_2>2</param_2>
        </seq_node>
    </complex_node>
</typ:add>
```

Looks like someone committed that code by mistake.

Secondly, code that is implemented in Calculator service does not allow to have whitespaces between request elements. It takes any first node hoping it is an element, but fails, because takes text node between elements.

To start that example without modification of the service:

1. use one of `sub`, `div`, `mul` operations.
2. remove all whitespaces in request element like that:

`<typ:sub><param_1>3</param_1><param_2>2</param_2></typ:sub>`

Then you will be able to call the service.

If you want to see fully working Calculator service, you can [compile Axis2/C](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/InstallationManualWindowsSource) from axis2-unofficial project (or [install it from  binary archive](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/InstallationManualWindowsBinary)).

Or, you can apply [that](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/source/detail?r=fed6120deedc4b28fe7e231fd83d1a4cac79c8c9) changes to the original source code and recompile it.